# Google Sheet textjoin as criterion in sumifs not working

Tags: google-sheets-formula, sumifs, textjoin

Hi I am trying to get the following formula to work unsuccessfully:
=ARRAYFORMULA(sumifs(B1:B9,REGEXMATCH(A1:A9,""""&textjoin("|",1,E1:E2)&""""),TRUE,C1:C9,F1))

Cells E1=a E2=b

This formula gets the desired results:
=ARRAYFORMULA(sumifs(B1:B9,regexmatch(A1:A9,"a|b"),true,C1:C9,F1))

and """"&TEXTjoin("|",1,E1:E8)&"""" results in "a|b"

Need some guidance please. Thanks.

a   1   nail        a   nail
b   2   nail        b
c   3   nail
a   10  hammer
b   11  hammer
c   12  hammer
a   20  nail
b   21  screw
c   22  screw

=ARRAYFORMULA(sumifs(B1:B9,REGEXMATCH(A1:A9,""""&textjoin("|",1,E1:E2)&""""),TRUE,C1:C9,F1)) results 0

=ARRAYFORMULA(sumifs(B1:B9,regexmatch(A1:A9,"a|b"),true,C1:C9,F1)) results 23

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EgEWrq_JzW47n4lORQJPaybQ-Ff-BTQQqTHp46LuRwc/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=sumifs(B:B,C:C,F1,index(--regexmatch(A:A,textjoin("|",1,E:E))),1)
```

[image]

***Updated formula:***

```
=sumifs(B:B,C:C,F1,index(xmatch(A:A,E:E)^0),1)
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work except for one issue. When I change cells in column A to text that contain a '+' anywhere in the cell, that row is not counted. Doesn't matter if I use static criterion or index. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EgEWrq_JzW47n4lORQJPaybQ-Ff-BTQQqTHp46LuRwc/edit#gid=0

Comment: Try the updated formula added to the answer. regex needs quite a few characters (*+|?[]().*) to be escaped with backslash and all; better to go with *xmatch*